How to exclude certain projects from being tested in a .NET project using XUnit and Coverlet
So I have a API project, and a Services project in a Visual Studio Solution. I also have separate api.tests.csproj and services.tests.csproj projects. I have a command like dotnet test ... /p:Threshold=40 that must be run. I have no control over this command. When it generates the coverage report, in the api.tests portion of the testing, it also tests the services project, and it doesn't pass the threshold, since all my services tests are in the services.tests.csproj. How do I get the api.tests.csproj to stop testing the services, since all my services tests are in another project?
I've tried removing Services from the api.tests.csproj file, and I've tried adding services.tests.csproj to the api.tests.csproj file, and I expected either the tests to be imported from services.tests.csproj to api.tests.csproj or for services to be excluded entirely from api.tests.csproj. Neither of which have done anything.
